# In python, is there a way to vectorize adding the previous row to the current one?

Tags: python

Is there a way for me to vectorize adding the values from one row to all the subsequent rows in a vectorized manner in python?

I was trying to use dataframe to get there but was struggling to vectorize it. This can be done with a for loop.

For example, if I use a table like this:

### Table A

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 7 | 0 | 1 |

and add this to another table:

### Table B

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

the result would be:

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 22 |
| 2 | 10 | 11 | 22 |
| 3 | 10 | 12 | 24 |
| 4 | 17 | 12 | 25 |

The for loop of this would be something like this:

```
tableA.ix[0, :] = tableA.ix[0, :] + tableB.ix[i, :]

for i in range(1, len(tableA.index)):
   tableA.ix[i, :] = tableA.ix[i-1, :] + tableB.ix[i, :]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
df3 = df1.cumsum(axis = 0).add(df2.cumsum(axis = 0), fill_value=0)
df3["INDEX"] = range(1,df3.shape[0]+1)

# Output;
   INDEX   A   B   C
0      1  10  11  22
1      2  10  11  22
2      3  10  12  24
3      4  17  12  25
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Can you please help me understand what voodoo magic is happening in this?

Comment: Glad to help... Magic is simple... first doing the cumulative sum using .cumsum & keep axis=0, so that sum happens row wise... then using another pandas property of .add, we are adding both data frames on top of another cell wise... & ofcourse filling up nan by zeros if there is any...